# First active_record insert id is set to NULL automatically

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

I have this schema:

```
create_table :tweets, id: false do |t|
  # we'll use the id to store the actual tweet ID
  t.integer :id, null: false
  t.string :text
  t.datetime :created_at
  t.index :created_at
end
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I'm trying to use active_record, but I will provide my own `id` values on each insert.

Now when I try to insert the same thing twice, I get an error the first time, but it works after that:

```
    > Tweet.create(id: 123, text: 'foo', created_at: Time.now))
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR
:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint                       
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, foo, 2014-10-06 15:45:46.149613).
: INSERT INTO "tweets" ("created_at", "text") VALUES ($1, $2)
from /home/mapleoin/tweetwatch/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/l
ib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:834:in `get_last_result'   

   > Tweet.create(id: 123, text: 'foo', created_at: Time.now))
   => #<Tweet id: 123, text: "foo", created_at: "2014-10-06 17:45:57">
```

Using postgresql with the `pg` gem with `active_record 4.1.6`

So why is the first insert differetn?

Comment: using `id` as a non-identity column is risky (possible, but needs some tweaks in your model). By default it always pass nil for id and lets database to autopopulate it. Would you consider using different name?

Comment: Yes, better to call it tweet_id or something to save a lot of pain, even if it's possible. (Also, Twitter uses 64-bit IDs for tweets so I think it should be a :bigint, not :integer)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?